# How to split numbered string joined with operator and put values in different double variables?

Tags: regex, string, kotlin, split

I am working on Kotlin project. I have read input from TextView to string,

```
eg, "1000+3.9*4"
```

here, is + and * but can be any operator instead.
now, how to separate these three values and store them in different variables?
Also wanted only three values but if put

```
eg, "1000+4.5-4/5"
```

now there are four values, this should not work or extract only three and reject all others
Please help me how to do this in Kotlin.
Can it be by Regex?
Also suggest on how to start with Regex for beginners.
Thank You!

Comment: Split on `[^\d.]+` and count the number of elements retrned.

Comment: `[*+\-\/]`....?

Comment: Do share what have you tried so far, that will help everyone to better understand your question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the solution concern, So, i havetried what regex  @41686d654 have suggested it worked but giving a warining : Redundant character escape \/\

Comment: i am getting this error now :java: illegal escape character

Comment: Finally, this helps [^\\d.]+